# Cannot read property 'lang' of undefined at ToolbarStrings.setLocale

Tags: javascript

I got the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lang' of undefined
at ToolbarStrings.setLocale (toolbar-min.js:9)
at Object.start (toolbar-min.js:41)
at toolbar-min.js:41
ToolbarStrings.setLocale @ toolbar-min.js:9
start @ toolbar-min.js:41
(anonymous) @ toolbar-min.js:41
```

for the following code

```
function ToolbarStrings(){var a="EN";this.setLocale=function(){
    var b=document.getElementsByTagName("<html>")[0],
    c=document.getElementsByTagName("<body>")[0];
    this.locale=(b.lang?b.lang:b.getAttribute("xml:lang")?b.getAttribute("xml:lang"):c.lang?c.lang:a).substr(0,2).toUpperCase(),
    this.locale&&traduction[this.locale]||(this.locale=a),
    this.ForceDefaultLocale&&(this.locale=this.ForceDefaultLocale)
}
```

in fact this is just a part of [this JavaScript file](https://agencescoop-eguidelisieux.pf5.wpserveur.net/wp-content/themes/oceanwp-child-theme-master/myconfortplus/js/toolbar-min.js) i'm using, 
i don't know if there is a problem with the syntax or something else

can you help me find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
var b=document.getElementsByTagName("<html>")[0],
    c=document.getElementsByTagName("<body>")[0];
```

To this:

```
var b=document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0],
    c=document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
```

**Explanation:**

The error is stating that you are trying to use the `lang` property on a variable that is `undefined`. This indicates that the `b` or `c` variables are undefined.

The reason is because it could not find an element by tag name `<html>` because that is invalid. It should be `html` (without angle brackets).

Comment: now i got another error :                                                                                 
GET https://agencescoop-eguidelisieux.pf5.wpserveur.net/wp-content/themes/oceanwp-child-theme-master/myconfortplus/cookie.html?hostname=agencescoop-eguidelisieux.pf5.wpserveur.net&origin=https://agencescoop-eguidelisieux.pf5.wpserveur.net/ 404
UciStorage @ toolbar-min.js:10
start @ toolbar-min.js:42
window.onload @ toolbar-min.js:42
window.onload @ waypoints.min.js:1
load (async)
(anonymous) @ waypoints.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ waypoints.min.js:1

Comment: @MyungHee, doesn't seem like that has anything to do with the code in your question. Sounds like the problem was solved and a new problem has arose somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be trying to get the [language declaration in your HTML](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-language-declarations). This would look something like this:

```
<html lang="en">
```

But the line `document.getElementsByTagName("<html>")[0]` returns nothing, hence why `b.lang` fails. You don't have an `<<html>>` tag in your document, since `getElementByTagName` is looking for that name *inside* the brackets. You need `document.getElementsByTagName("html")`

```js
let htmlTags = document.getElementsByTagName("html");

let htmlTagsInExtraAngleBrackets = document.getElementsByTagName("<html>");

console.log('number of elements selected with "html"', htmlTags.length)
console.log('number of elements selected with "<html>"', htmlTagsInExtraAngleBrackets.length)
```

Comment: I'm using a child theme in Wordpress an i'v added the toolbar-min.js file in functions.php of that child theme, and i don't know why it says that i don't have HTML tag element ?

Comment: @MyungHee no, you don't have `<<html>>` elements. I've added an example. When you have `document.getElementsByTagName("html")` it will check for `<html>` tags, but document.getElementsByTagName("<html>")` will check for `<<html>>` tags.